# JQuery pros/cons of undefined, null, and empty array for not-applicable field

Tags: rest, jquery

Is it preferable, from a UI developers perspective, for a json rest service response that is consumed by jquery with a not applicable field that is normally an array to leave that field undefined, null, or as an empty array?

Answer (score 0):

It depends somewhat on the semantics of the interface, but I'd vote for an empty array. Depending on how much your client trusts the server, that could make parsing the response easier, e.g.

```
    for (var idx=0; idx<response.arr.length; idx++) {
        // do something with response.arr[idx];
    }
```

If you use `null` or `undefined` your client code needs an extra statement to avoid errors:

```
    if (response.arr) {
        for (var idx=0; idx<response.arr.length; idx++) {
            // do something with response.arr[idx];
        }
    }
```

Of course, there are lots of variations that can optimize the latter a bit, and there are also ways for the paranoid to make it even more complicated (e.g. verify that the type of `response.arr` is really an array in addition to making sure it's truthy).

Bottom line, of course, is "it depends," but all options can be made to work fine.